# ui-router modal window with parent state

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-router

There's a lot of documentation about opening modal windows when going to a specific state, some people use 'onEnter', others' use the '$stateChangeStart' event.

But the issue I'm having with both of those is that when going to that url directly, there isn't any content loaded underneath the modal window.

For example:
 1. Users goes to www.mysite.com
 2. User click the link that opens a model: www.mysite.com/#/signup
 3. User sees the signup modal window with the original content underneath

But when a user goes directly to www.mysite.com/#/signup, this doesn't happen.

Currently I have a parent route that handles all my modal windows, as following:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('modal', {
        parent: 'home',
        abstract: true,
        url: '',
        data: {
            modal: true  
        },
        onEnter: ['$state', '$modal', function($state, $modal) {
            console.log('open modal'); 

            $modal.open({
                template: '<div ui-view="modal"></div>',
                backdrop: true
            }).result.then(function() {
                $state.go('home'); 
            }, function(reason) {
                if(!reason || reason == 'backdrop click') $state.go('home');   
            });
        }]
    });
```

While this works, I want to be able to dynamically set the parent route, as this will be the content that is underneath my modal window.

Is there any way to do this? Or is there any other method that allows me to open the modal window with whatever content is underneath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `UI-Router Extra` - `Sticky States` has helped me solve my problem, there's a few issues that there's no underlaying state when you open a modal directly, but those are issues that can be solved.
http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky